# Strange behavior of XPathSelectElements and namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have this kind of xml

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.">
  <soap-env:body>
    <SomeElement xmlns='http://www.MySite.com/SOAP' />
  </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

And I'm trying to get 'SomeElement' node with xpath, like this

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(strXml);
var xmlNamespace = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDocument.CreateReader().NameTable);
xmlNamespace.AddNamespace("soap-env", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.");
xmlNamespace.AddNamespace("", "http://www.MySite.com/SOAP");
var xmlBody = xDocument.XPathSelectElements("soap-env:envelope/soap-env:body/SomeElement", xmlNamespace);
```

and getting null returned in `xmlBody`, but if I remove  `xmlns='http://www.MySite.com/SOAP'` namespace everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefix the default namespace I would think it should work, so change:

```
xmlNamespace.AddNamespace("", "http://www.MySite.com/SOAP");
var xmlBody = xDocument.XPathSelectElements("soap-env:envelope/soap-env:body/SomeElement", xmlNamespace);
```

To:

```
xmlNamespace.AddNamespace("pref", "http://www.MySite.com/SOAP");
var xmlBody = xDocument.XPathSelectElements("soap-env:envelope/soap-env:body/pref:SomeElement", xmlNamespace);
```